# How can I get a GMap Marker field to be a target in my Feeds importer?

Tags: 7, feeds, google-maps

I have site that needs to import a CSV of hundreds of locations to be displayed on a GMap. I have set up an importer in the Feeds module that successfully imports a CSV containing Title, address, longitude and latitude. The properties all appear on my GMap view correctly.

Now, I would also like to assign different colored markers for various location types that I am importing. I have my content type properly set up with a GMap Marker Field (if I manually assign a Marker to each node they appear with the correct markers on my map view). However, on my Feed importer Mapping page, the GMap Marker field is not appearing as a *target* option in the dropdown list.

**How can I get the GMap Marker field to appear as a target option in the feeds importer?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping targets for fields are not automatically available. For each field, a Feeds target must be written. Feeds targets for fields provided by Drupal core should be provided by Feeds itself, but Feeds targets for fields provided by a contrib module, should be provided by that contrib module.

You can do the following:

1. Open an issue in the [GMap issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/gmap) and request a mapper for the GMap Marker field.
2. Implement the Feeds target yourself. For documentation, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/feeds/the-developers-guide-to-feeds/the-developers-guide-to-feeds#mappingapi. While the process explained there still works, the documentation is slightly outdated. The recommended way of adding a target now is to use the hook `hook_feeds_processor_targets()` instead of `hook_feeds_processor_targets_alter()`. Also in the target callback, the language of the target can be found in `$mapping['language']`. See feeds.api.php for more information.